# Jquery refers always to the starting DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to understand way the function, triggered by the event click, is executed also after the first time.

I thought that changing the id of my  the function would no longer be performed.

Seems that jquery code continue to refer to the original DOM. Why? And what can I do in order to upgrade the DOM object after the first execution?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").on('click',function(){
      $(this).children().each(function () {
        globalObj[this.value] = this.innerHTML;
    });
      $(this).attr("id","select2");
      });
 });
```

Comment: *"I thought that changing the id of my the function would no longer be performed."* The selector is only used to initially **find** the element.

Comment: Yes @FelixK I have removed that line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that changing the id of my the function would no longer be performed.

No, because once the event is binded to an element it is set to **that** element, it doesn't matter which attributes you change. If you want it to be executed only one you can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) or, to stop the binding of a function you can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

> Seems that jquery code continue to refer to the original DOM

Yes, because jQuery, being cross browser, assigns the click event with `Element.addEventListener` or `Element.attachEvent`(depending on the browser). If you want to remove the events you have to use one of the solutions listed before, which use `removeEventListener` and `detachEvent`.

Comment: I was modifing the id in order to avoid subsequent executions. In this casee I can simply use .one(). Thank you :)

Comment: `.one()` is good if you only ever need the one time. But if you actually want a handler to be called repeatedly but only when a selector matches the element you can use a delegated event handler.

Answer (score 1):

the event is attached with the DOM element not with the id, at first you get the element by id `select1` it returns a dom object, you bind click event for this object, if you changed the id that doesn't mean that you created a new object if you want to remove the event you can just by unbind it

```
$(this).unbind('click')
//OR
$(this).off('click')
```

of let the event works for one time

```
$("#select1").one('click',... // the function is "onE" not "on"
```